# People Working on Dark Matter Simulations

Tags: dark-matter

I am interested in simulations regarding dark matter. I am looking for more details and reading material on the same. I was really hoping to get some guidance from someone working in that field. Can you guys please drop the names of some people that I could get in touch with for guidance? Thanks!

Edit: I've read Profumo and Tanedo's lecture/notes on Dark Matter. Currently my professor has asked me to read Bauer's Yet Another Introduction to Dark Matter. I haven't read anything about dark matter simulations as of yet.

Comment: To make this answerable you should include the prior research that you have done.  For example what advice have your professors given you? What research papers have you read? What have you already done to answer this question?

Comment: I've read Profumo and Tanedo's lecture/notes on Dark Matter. Currently my professor has asked me to read Bauer's Yet Another Introduction to Dark Matter. I haven't read anything about dark matter simulations as of yet.

Comment: Can you add that info to the question, comments tend to get deleted

Comment: The millennium simulation webpage has a bunch of references on the bottom of their website https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/galform/virgo/millennium/ . Note that this is from 2006 and they have published updated millennium simulations 2.0 by now.

Answer (score 1):

Not a list such a list would be too long, but how you should be investigating using the various internet tools.  You could start with searches on google scholar and arxiv:

- https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=dark+matter+simulation&btnG=
- https://arxiv.org/search/?query=dark+matter+simulation&searchtype=all&source=header

You can then follow up interesting papers, look at their bibliographies or the list of citations on G. Scholar:

- https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=16013787899598752647&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en

This quickly leads to names

- Joanne D Cohn
- Anatoly A. Klypin
- Cullan Howlett
- (+ many more)

and even downloadable packages for simulation

- https://cullanhowlett.github.io/l-picola/

In five minutes I found literally thousands of potential names matched with the papers they had written, so I know what their particular interest is.